# Funny OCR-situation

Tags: pdf, ocr, ghostscript, tesseract-ocr

I have a multipage scanned 300 dpi PDF-file on an Ubuntu 16.04 system.

When I run the following command:

```
pdfocr -t -l swe -i *.pdf -o newfile.pdf
```

It results in a perfectly OCR-read file. Every single word is searchable whatever size and shape of the fonts.

However the next step in the process is converting this PDF to PDF/A-1b. This in done by Ghostscript 9.18 running the command:

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=konverterade/$i $i
```

The resulting file is validated as a correct PDF/A-1b-file, but the searchability of the file has alterered really badly. It seems as if Ghostscript is trashing the OCR.

Anyone has an idea what's going on?

Many thanks in advance.

/Paul

Comment: Perhaps pdfocr has unusual encoding. Have you tried reversing the steps (make it compliant, then ocr)?

Comment: Well, I guess that is not supposed to be done. A PDF/A-compliancy locks the file. After that you can't add, subtract och alter anything within the file.

Comment: Possibly bug? "unicode" (utf/encode/magic) problem? skew? https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/357

Comment: Yorik, it seems as if you are right! I have looked into your link before and I am now convinced there is as bug in Ghostscript producing the error. I wonder if the team behind Ghostscript is aware of this problem?

Comment: Since there seems to be a problem with Ghostscript at the moment - I also tried version 9.19 with the same result - I would like to try to convert from PDF to PDF/A-1b with PDFBox which is a Java-based software. Does anyone have the slightest idea how this is done? I've been googling around for some kind of usage description how to do this but so far with no success.